# Sony Xperia isn't able to be in NFC target role with Android V4.1.2

Tags: android, sony, nfc-p2p, sony-xperia

I am working with a NFC reader and several NFC phones to establish a NFC P2P connection in passive mode. The NFC reader is always in initiator role while the NFC phones are always in target role.

I am using a Sony Xperia (LT26i) amongst others, which worked well with the Android version 4.0.4 (Build 6.1.A.2.55). I could establish the connection and was able to send and receive NDEF messages. But since the update to the Android version 4.1.2 (Build 6.2.B.1.96), the Xperia isn't apparent on Sony FeliCa standard anymore. That means, I get no answer from the phone on the polling requests. Therefore I am not able to use the Xperia as a NFC passive target.

Does anyone have the same problems or are there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: At which bitrates are you polling? I have seen a similar issue with phones that have Google Wallet installed.

Comment: I am polling with 212 kbps. I have never polled with 424 kbps, but I will try that. What was the solution for the Google Wallet issue?

Comment: Polling with 424 kbps also didn't work.

Comment: And what about 106kbps? Did you try that?

Comment: I've tried 106kbps with ISO14443A, also without success.